# Исправить зацикленность отправки формы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

Для валидации формы я использую jquery + jqueryvalidate + additianal-methods. Форма валидируется и даже отправляется. Проблема в том, что перед отправкой метод submitHandler выполняется примерно 600 раз, что иногда приводит к отмене отправки в браузерах типа IE.

В целях отладки я поставил `console.log()` в submitHandler:

```
submitHandler: function(){
            console.log('submitHandler!');
            $( "#brief_form_new_test" ).submit();
        }
```

Видно, что в консоли он выводится несколько сот раз.

Вот [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wTMv3/700/).

Хотелось бы, чтобы submitHandler выполнялся только один раз, как и положено.

```
validation:
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        invalidHandler: function(){ 
            var fileInput = document.getElementById("fileUploadField");

            if($('#brief_form_new_test .file-add input.error').length >= 1){
                $('.file-add').css({
                    'background': 'url("../img/attache.png") 0 -88px'
                });
            }else{ 
                $('.file-add').css({
                    'background': 'url("../img/attache.png") 0 0'
                });
            };

            //console.log("not submitted!");
        },
        submitHandler: function(){
            console.log('submitHandler!');
            $( "#brief_form_new_test" ).submit();
        }
    });

    $.validator.addMethod("checkFileSize",function(value, element) {
        // check filesize
        var fileInput = document.getElementById("fileUploadField"),
            fileSize;

        if(fileInput.files[0]){
            if(fileInput.files[0].size > 134217728){
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }else{
            $('.file-add label.error').empty();
            return true
        }
    }, "Размер файла превышен");

    $().ready(function(){
        $("#brief_form_new_test").validate({
            rules: {
                attachment: {
                    required: false,
                    checkFileSize: true,
                    extension: "doc,docx,txt,pdf,jpg,jpeg,png"
                },
                message_new: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10
                },
                name_new: "required",
                email_new: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                phone_new: {
                    "required": true,
                    "pattern": /[-0-9 -()+]+$/
                }
            },
            messages: {
                attachment: {
                    required: 'File required',
                    checkFileSize: 'Размер файла превышен',
                    extension: "Неверный формат файла",
                },
                message_new: {
                    required: "Коротко опишите проект",
                    minlength: "Введите не менее 10 символов"
                },
                name_new: "Введите ФИО",
                email_new: "Введите корректный адрес",
                phone_new: {
                    required: "Введите телефон",
                    pattern: "Введите корректный телефон"
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment:      submitHandler: function(form){
        console.log('submitHandler!');
        form.submit();
    }
так попробуй

Comment: так написано в документации к плагину. я так пробовал, в консоли появляется следующая ошибка:  Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wTMv3/704/

Comment: А может, стоит заменить

     $().ready(function() на $(document).ready(function()